# How to implement carousel effect for recylerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, carousel, linearlayoutmanager

I'm trying to implement the carousel-like effect in recyclerView [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe3Qm.jpg). I can't find the right function for scaling and moving the views. Also, the views that reached the top of recyclerview must not scroll out of recyclerview's edges but stick to them

```
override fun scrollVerticallyBy(dy: Int, recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state: RecyclerView.State?): Int {
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val item = getChildAt(i)
            val recyclerCenter = height / 2f
            val distance = max(abs(recyclerCenter - getDecoratedTop(item!!) / 2f), recyclerCenter - getDecoratedTop(item) / 2f)
            val ratio = (recyclerCenter - item.height / 2f - distance) / (recyclerCenter - item.height / 2f) + 1
            item.translationZ = (ratio * 1000f)
            item.alpha = ratio
            item.translationY = -(ratio.pow(2)*10)
            item.scaleX = ratio
            item.scaleY = ratio
        }
        return super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state)
    }
```

I've already tried some solutions, like carousellayoutmanager, but all of them scaling all views, that not in center of recyclerview

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do it outside of inheriting a RecyclerView. Layouting is done in onLayoutChildren I believe. BUT you can use CarouselLayoutManager but instead of using standard PostLayoutListener you can write your own. All transformation is calculated here: https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager/blob/master/CarouselLayoutManager/carousel/src/main/java/com/azoft/carousellayoutmanager/CarouselZoomPostLayoutListener.java Just make your own and attach it to CarouselLayoutManager by setPostLayoutListener.

Comment: Did you mean this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/StackView